# C ++ - Segmentation fault without accessing any index in a vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the array subscript operator and provide custom exception handling mechanism to the `[]` operator. The vectors are indexed using `at()` and the code catches the exception but it then crashes into a segmentation fault.

Here are the sample codes

```
/* MySQLQueryResult.cpp */
class MySQLQueryResult : public mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult  {

         ...

         const mysqlpp::Row& MySQLQueryResult::operator[]( int index ) const
        {

            try {
                std::cout << " Called Array Subscript " << this->size( ) << std::endl ;
                if ( this->size() > 0 && this->size() > index ) {
                    return this->at( index ) ;
                } else {
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
                }
            } catch ( std::exception& excpn_ob ) {
                std::cout << " Exception caught : " << excpn_ob.what( ) << std::endl ;
            }



        }

               ...  


}



/* QueryRow.cpp */
class QueryRow : public mysqlpp::Row {
   const mysqlpp::String& QueryRow::operator[]( int index ) const
        {

            try {
                std::cout << " Called Array Subscript In Row :  " << this->size( ) << "  " << std::endl ;
                std::cout << index << std::endl;
                if ( this->size() > 0 && this->size() > index ) {
                    return this->at( index ) ;
                } else {
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");  
                }
            } catch ( std::exception& excpn_ob ) {

                std::cout << " Exception caught : " << excpn_ob.what( ) << std::endl ;
            }


        }
}

    /* main.cpp */
    int main() {
    MySQLQueryResult res = getConfirmationData( ( string ) row.at( 0 ) ) ;

    QueryRow qm = res[0];

    cout << qm[2] << endl ; // this prints "Bill Watson"
    cout << qm[10] << endl; // this prints "Exception caught : Index out of range" and then gives a Seg fault and crashes

   mysqlpp::String srt = qm[10];  // this prints "Exception caught : Index out of range" and then gives a Seg fault and crashes
    }
```

So i get both the program messages " Called Array Subscript  " and "Called Array Subscript In Row" but then it catches the exception and then crashes. I specifically use `at()` in order to catch such out of range exception and prevent program crashes as its a long running code.
 But in here , esp in `QueryRow::operator[]` it catches the exception and then crashes. How do i avoid this Seg fault . Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: You guarantee to return a reference to a valid object. But after catching the exception, you do not return anything. How did you even get the compiler to eat this code and bring it into a binary?

Comment: What are size() and at()? They are not members of StoreQueryResult

Comment: @The Wavelength lol . I'm using gcc 4.7.2 and it only gives a warning `../Libraries/QueryRow.cpp:43:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` . In case of exception i want it to return 0 but if i do that the compiler gives a error of a non compatible return type conversion

Comment: @galinette As both of this class inherits from std::vector so they are provided for

Comment: @Maxx As pointed out in the comments, the issue is with you not returning anything in the `catch` block. Let's ignore the segfault for a moment and address this question, assuming the assignment did not crash : What do you want the behaviour of `srt` to be when it is assigned a non-existent entry, say `qm[10]`? The answer to this question will tell you what you need `operator[]` to return from the `catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

I think the segmentation fault is because you are using the return value `qm[10]` for cout, but when the exception is caught, you don't return anything. Just call `qm[10]` without printing it and it should run fine.

Comment: No i've tried assigning it . `mysqlpp::String srt = qm[10];` and the behavior is still the same. Throws the exception and then Seg fault and crashes

Comment: Well, you have undefined behaviour as soon as you run the function and don't return anything. You really should rethrow the exception.

Comment: Don't assign it too. Don't use the return value at all. Just write `qm[10];` and please tell what happens.

Comment: @Mankarse thats the whole purpose of making this class. Because previously it was just indexing using `at()` and once a out of range exception occurs it just takes the control out of the whole loop and the statements after the line at which the exception occurred never gets executed. So this class catches the exception at the point it happens. But its not working either :-(

Comment: @SagarJha Yes just writing `qm[10]` works fine and doesn't crashes. But i need to be able to assign it or pass the value to a function.

Comment: @Maxx: If the index is incorrect, the code *can't* continue running, because there isn't a valid value any more. Perhaps you should add a `static mysqlpp::String const` containing some 'error' value, and return a reference to that `mysqlpp::String` when the exception is caught.

Comment: It seems like a poor design though. You should catch the exception at the outer level (at the main event loop, or connection loop, or whatever loop keeps the program running for a long time), swallow it there and then continue (rather than swallowing it at the bottom level). If there is a bug in some part of the code, that code can't meaningfully keep running anyway.

Comment: @Mankarse yes i'm also quite concerned about the design. One of the main objective of the code is to keep on running even in case of out of range errors. As basically the code gets some bunch of data from some tables in mysql and then sorts the data and put it in other table. Previously i was range checking each time i used a vector indexing operation like `qm[10]` but the code got littered with too many if-else statements checking if the size of the vector is not less than the given index . So i was trying to refactor the code in order to remove so many if else statements

Comment: @Mankarse yes i have now returned a `const mysqlpp::String` and it works now without giving a Seg fault. Can you post your comment as an answer  so that i can mark it as accepted and close this question